# Duplicate interface definition for class 'IGListSectionController'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I had this problem, when i installed IGListSectionController via Cocoapods in old objective-c project. Has anyone encountered this problem?

```
Duplicate interface definition for class 'IGListSectionController'
```